# Convert NSDate to String with strftime

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, nsdate, strftime

How would I convert an NSDate to a NSString, formatted with strftime specifiers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you could use strftime.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
time_t time = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
struct tm timeStruct;
localtime_r(&time, &timeStruct);
char buffer[80];
strftime(buffer, 80, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", &timeStruct);
NSString *dateStr = [NSString stringWithCString:buffer encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

I hope it's correct.

Comment: Thanks a ton!  Here's what I ended up using: https://gist.github.com/cd7b71db01bfa7a4d778  Turns out I just didn't know the "time_t time" expression shouldn't be setup.   Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an `NSDateFormatter`, using `setDateFormat:`. [Here's the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: You make a fair point; it doesn't use strftime formatting. As Objective C is a superset of C, you can of course use strftime directly. As you were going from NSDate to NSString, I assumed you'd prefer to keep everything in Cocoa.

Comment: IIRC, you can use strftime-style formatting if you call `-[yourFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_0]`.

Comment: Wait…I take it back. You can't use `NSDateFormatterBehavior10_0` on the iPhone.