# strftime no blank before %e single-digit days?

Tags: objective-c, c, nsstring, char, strftime

I want to [Convert NSDate to String with strftime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008876/convert-nsdate-to-string-with-strftime), but `%e` precedes a single-digit day by a blank. How do I prevent this? Or, if I can't, what's the best way to remove the char at position 4 if it's a space?

```
// TODO: Don't precede %e with blank for single-digit days. @issue
char buffer[22]; // Sep 22, 2012 12:15 PM -- 21 chars + 1 for NUL terminator \0
time_t time = [message.sentDate timeIntervalSince1970] - [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
strftime(buffer, 22, "%b %e, %Y %l:%M %p", localtime(&time));
messageSentDateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithCString:buffer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try the GNU C extension to skip space padding of numerics by inserting a minus sign in the format: `%-e`.  These are supported in [Apple's libraries](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/strftime.3.html).

Comment: Nice. Thanks! I also changed %l to %-l.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the least efficient solution is to replace the last line with:

```
NSMutableString *sentDateLabelText = [NSMutableString stringWithCString:buffer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if ([sentDateLabelText characterAtIndex:4] == ' ') {
    [sentDateLabelText deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(4, 1)];
}
messageSentDateLabel.text = sentDateLabelText;
```